# Are there non-serializable entity-fields-types?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

If I inspect the columns of a database-table is use [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

In result-set-column 5 they return a int-value from java.sql.Types:

> 5. DATA_TYPE int => SQL type from java.sql.Types

Can we assume that the type of the Java-Field in the Hibernate-entity extends Serializable?

I am sure that streaming using outputstream/inputstream and arrays are one exception. Does there exists more exceptions?

Comment: The meaning of the `DATA_TYPE` column has nothing to do with hibernate entities. And Hibernate types don't have to be serializable. It is unclear what you're really asking.

Comment: Yes, nothing. `DATA_TYPE` defines the JDBC type of a column, which is not related to Hibernate entities.

Comment: It is still not very clear what you're asking, but I guess you want to know if the Java types mapped by JDBC for a `java.sql.Types` code is serializable or not. I suggest you download the JDBC 4.3 specification and consult the mappings defined in Appendix B and then check if the types are serializable or not. In addition, be aware that Hibernate dialects can define additional (database specific) mappings.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I dont ask if `java.sql.Types` are serializable. If it is not clear, what else could be meant?

Comment: Read my comment again. With _"Java types"_ I'm not talking about the `java.sql.Types` codes, but the types (eg `java.lang.String` or `java.time.OffsetDateTime`) that JDBC specifies for mapping with specific type codes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I repeat: I dont ask if `java.sql.Types` are serializable. And with no word  I substate your question that it is "talking" and nor it compares types to `java.sql.Types`. I compleatly understand your term and do not need to read your comment twice.

Comment: I'm not talking about `java.sql.Types` being serializable, I'm talking about the Java types that JDBC maps for those type codes (eg `java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE` maps to `java.time.OffsetDateTime` which is serializable, and `java.types.BLOB` maps to `java.sql.Blob` which is not necessarily serializable, etc. Because in the end, Hibernate will - by default - use the JDBC type mappings. I'm suggesting how you can find out for yourself. However even with such mappings, it is still possible to create Hibernate entities with fields with non-serializable types (custom type mapping, etc)